# Why do i get reverse match error in get_absolute_url method?- Django

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name ="profile/profile_view.html"

class ProfileEdit(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = ProfileForm
    template_name="profile/profile_new.html"
```

models.py

```
#.... models
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('user:user_profile', kwargs={ "slug": self.slug })
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w.@+-]+)/edit/$', ProfileEdit.as_view(), name='profile_edit'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w.@+-]+)/$', ProfileView.as_view(), name='user_profile'),
```

**Reverse for 'user_profile' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': 'rahul'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []**

I dont understand i get the correct slug value but what is the right way to pass it to the url patterns?

Comment: Is your app in the installed apps setting that includes those urls?

Comment: yes! both detail view and update view works fine.. after the post request in the updateview i want to redirect to the detailview

Comment: And the `user` namespace definitely exists? (please include the relevant base url)

Comment: `url(r'^', include('user.urls', name='user')),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.include) you need to specify a `namespace`, not a `name`

```
url(r'^', include('user.urls', namespace='user'))
```

Comment: It works in the model but how do i do the same in `settings.py`
`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ('profile:user_profile', kwargs={ "slug": self.slug })`

Comment: @Rahul - Thats a separate question (for which you should raise a new question. The normal solution is `reverse_lazy` but that won't work since there is no self

Comment: is it better practice to write custom `loginview` instead of the default `auth_views.login`

Comment: Thats a separate question for which you should raise a new question complete with what you have tried and researched.